# RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance

Tags: node.js, next.js, cpanel

I'm trying to host my nextjs web in cpanel and i get this error when i run build inside the cpanel

```
returncode: 1
stdout:
> haba@0.1.0 build
> next build
stderr:
unhandledRejection RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance
    at lazyllhttp (eval at requireWithFakeGlobalScope (/home/habadati/nodevenv/haba/20/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/load.js:64:3), <anonymous>:9972:32)
```

I tried a similar question's solution which says you can use putty to run ssh commands in your local machine but it leads to a dead end.
also when i try proceeding to run start in the cpanel there's an error

```
returncode: 1
stdout:
> haba@0.1.0 start
> NODE_ENV=production node server.js
stderr:
undefined:9972
      return await WebAssembly.instantiate(mod, {
                               ^

RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance
    at lazyllhttp (eval at requireWithFakeGlobalScope (/home/habadati/nodevenv/haba/20/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/load.js:64:3), <anonymous>:9972:32)

Node.js v20.3.1
```

i had my server.js file from this [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the way?

Comment: not yet. I decided to deploy the site to netlify instead

Comment: Same issue with deploying to rocky linux machine.